Error Installing RXNFP Module in Python using pip or git clone
I am trying to install the RXNFP module in Python, but I am encountering errors during the installation process. I have followed the official instructions which suggest using Conda for handling dependencies, but I continue to face issues with pip install rxnfp, I also tried using git clone.
I already tried updating pip and installing the rust with this command:
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh

Could someone help me understand what might be going wrong and how to fix it?
Environment Details:

Operating System: macOS 14.4.1 (23E224)
Python version: 3.6
Conda version: conda 23.7.4

Here are the steps I have followed and the errors encountered:
conda create -n rxnfp python=3.6 -y
conda activate rxnfp
conda install -c rdkit rdkit=2020.03.3 -y
conda install -c tmap tmap -y
pip install rxnfp

Using these commands I encountered the following error:
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Users/diegodelozada/anaconda3/envs/rxnfp/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zc.lockfile->CherryPy>=18.1.0->faerun==0.3.20->rxnfp==0.1.0) (58.0.4)
Collecting jaraco.context>=4.1
  Using cached jaraco.context-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.4 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: tokenizers
  Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/diegodelozada/anaconda3/envs/rxnfp/bin/python /Users/diegodelozada/anaconda3/envs/rxnfp/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /var/folders/bf/7hsdtc_x6ls7z08gzy6qkbq00000gn/T/tmpoxxki8n2
       cwd: /private/var/folders/bf/7hsdtc_x6ls7z08gzy6qkbq00000gn/T/pip-install-2cckwo_g/tokenizers_6e884e60d0d24a9b97b39bb28e5a0cd7
  Complete output (51 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/models
  copying py_src/tokenizers/models/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/models
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/decoders
  copying py_src/tokenizers/decoders/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/decoders
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/normalizers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/normalizers/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/normalizers
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/pre_tokenizers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/pre_tokenizers/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/pre_tokenizers
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/processors
  copying py_src/tokenizers/processors/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/processors
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/trainers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/trainers/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/trainers
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/implementations
  copying py_src/tokenizers/implementations/byte_level_bpe.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/implementations
  copying py_src/tokenizers/implementations/sentencepiece_unigram.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/implementations
  copying py_src/tokenizers/implementations/sentencepiece_bpe.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/implementations
  copying py_src/tokenizers/implementations/base_tokenizer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/implementations
  copying py_src/tokenizers/implementations/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/implementations
  copying py_src/tokenizers/implementations/char_level_bpe.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/implementations
  copying py_src/tokenizers/implementations/bert_wordpiece.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/implementations
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/tools
  copying py_src/tokenizers/tools/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/tools
  copying py_src/tokenizers/tools/visualizer.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/tools
  copying py_src/tokenizers/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/models/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/models
  copying py_src/tokenizers/decoders/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/decoders
  copying py_src/tokenizers/normalizers/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/normalizers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/pre_tokenizers/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/pre_tokenizers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/processors/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/processors
  copying py_src/tokenizers/trainers/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/trainers
  copying py_src/tokenizers/tools/visualizer-styles.css -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/tokenizers/tools
  running build_ext
  running build_rust
  error: can't find Rust compiler
  
  If you are using an outdated pip version, it is possible a prebuilt wheel is available for this package but pip is not able to install from it. Installing from the wheel would avoid the need for a Rust compiler.
  
  To update pip, run:
  
      pip install --upgrade pip
  
  and then retry package installation.
  
  If you did intend to build this package from source, try installing a Rust compiler from your system package manager and ensure it is on the PATH during installation. Alternatively, rustup (available at https://rustup.rs) is the recommended way to download and update the Rust compiler toolchain.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
Failed to build tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


I thought you shouldn't mix conda and pip.

Diagnosis: you installed Rust but did not add it to your PATH environment variable.
Solution: after using rustup to install the Rust compiler, you should add it to your PATH environment variable.
from tokenizers site:
# Install with:
curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"

